# Determining IsAuthenticated in DRF Using DRF-JWT to retrieve a list testing with Postman

Tags: django, rest, api, django-rest-framework, jwt

So I'm using `DRF JWT` for my authentication. User submits credentials, and if valid, responds with a JWT that is stored in `sessionStorage`. Any time the user navigates the protected routes, the JWT `/api/auth/refresh` to refresh the token if it is still valid.

Anyway, moving on from authentication and onto protected routes where data is retrieved based on if the user is `IsAuthenticated` according to DRF. The problem is I am having difficulty figuring out how to determine `IsAuthenticated` in DRF without having the user supply credentials again. I should mention right now I am testing with Postman.

API URL:

```
/api/help/questions
```

I have the view as:

```
class GetQuestionsAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Help.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GetQuestionsSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]
```

The serializer is:

```
class GetQuestionsSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Help
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate(self, data):
        return data
```

I have a valid token from `/api/auth/signin/`. I'm trying to pass it on to the `/api/help/questions/` route to retrieve the list of questions.

`GET /api/help/questions/` doesn't work because it wants credentials. `Authentication credentials were not provided.`

`GET /api/help/questions/` with `Content-type: application/json` and 'Authorization`and the token in the header also says`Authentication credentials were not provided.`

Thought maybe it should be `POST` since I submitting credentials and expecting the questions as the server response if authentication is valid, but pretty much the same results.

I'm obviously not the most knowledgeable on this subject, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you defined in the django `settings.py` in `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`?  Maybe add a failing test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you put your token into Authorization header?
So after you login, you get a token and you should put it inside the headers on the request for your protected url like this:

`Authorization: JWT <your_token>`

Here's a sample using `curl`:

`curl -H "Authorization: JWT <your_token>" http://localhost:8000/protected-url/`

Comment: Geez, so simple. I did have the token in an authorization header, but didn't have the `JWT` before the token. Thanks!